# Share a git repository between multiple Visual Studio Team Services Projects

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I have multiple Projects in Visual Studio Team Services. A lot of our projects share code, as our systems were built using a monolithic approach. Because of this I need a way to share these git repositories between Team projects.

Is this possible and if so how do I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible (as far as I know) to share repositories across projects.

However you can create multiple teams under one project. Each team would get their own workspace (sprints, etc) but all teams can share the repositories registered at the project level.

Answer (score 2):

You  should never share code, it is a bad practice that leeds to loss of quality.

A better  approach would be to share the versioned binary  output  from your builds. There are a number of package  management tools  that make this easyer. The main one for the Microsoft stack is Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the specifics of using Visual Studio or how it integrates with git, but there are many ways to share git repos with others.

You can use [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/), [Github](https://github.com/), or another of a myriad of hosted solutions to host your git repo. If outsourcing your git server is unacceptable to your company, you can manage [your own git server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server).

For the actual workflow of sharing individual branches as they are produced, see [Atlassian's article on git workflows](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this like use Git Submodules or Git Fusion. Refer to this link for details: [Managing Projects Across Git Repositories](https://www.perforce.com/blog/121025/managing-projects-across-git-repositories)